# How to hide a link by using Id's?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring

In my application I'm hiding some links by using Ids. While loading pages a DB call will go and pick all Ids. Ids are nothing but Ids in the below sample code.

```
 <ul id="menu-content">           
      <li><a href="HomePage" id="HomeId"><spring:message code="label.home"/></a></li>
      <li><a href="loginPage" id="loginPageId"><spring:message code="label.login" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="define" id="defineId"><spring:message code="label.define" /></a></li>
 </ul>
```

I'll hide the links by using following code.
**AngularJS Controller**:

```
 'use strict';
app.factory('actionToPerform',['$http', function($http) {

    return {
        getCustomMenus: function($scope,data) {

            angular.forEach(data, function(key,value) { 
                angular.forEach(key, function(k,v) {    

                        var id=k.Identification;

                        var div = document.getElementById(id);
                        if(div !== null){
                        if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
                            div.style.display = 'none';
                        }
                        }
                });


            });

            return "Hello, World!";
        }
    };

 }]);
```

But my new requirement is I want to show only the Id's which came In onload function.In onload function I will get one or two Id's not all.
If I get one Id then I want to show that link only, Other links need to hide. How can I proceed. Thanks In Advance.

Comment: where is your div that you want to hide?

Comment: Hide everything by default, only show the ones retrieve. Instead of the other way around.

Comment: you could hide all divs and in a second method make visible only the ones you need to make visible

Comment: there div is a variable. I will hide <li> tag's (link's) not div's

Comment: correct your question first.And learn to how to ask question.

Comment: I will not get all id's. I will get one or two Id's only

Comment: @Hekmat I am sorry I am correcting my question

Comment: Why don't you use E2E binding of AngularJS by using `ng-show` or `ng-hide`? Looks like you dont know how AngularJS is working.

Comment: @lin Yes I am fresher to angularJs

Comment: Are you using angularjs ? if so provide the code of your controller

Comment: @ShivaGoudA any feedback or suggestions on my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily by using the E2E binding of AngularJS. For example by using [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide). AngularJS is very special and provides features like a E2E binding. In that way you don't need to make DOM injections like you tried before.

I also removed the attribute `id` from DOM. You don't need them while using the AngularJS way.

This is an example how you can implement show/hide some elements with AngularJS. In this case a button need to be pressed to hide elements. You can also hide element inside your controller or other function by injection the `$scope` params like `$scope.toggleMenuItem('homeId')`.

#### View

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="testController">
        <ul id="menu-content">
            <li><a href="HomePage" ng-hide="menuState.homeId"><spring:message code="label.home"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="loginPage" ng-hide="menuState.loginPageId"><spring:message code="label.login" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="define" ng-hide="menuState.defineId"><spring:message code="label.define" /></a></li>
        </ul>

        <button ng-click="toggleMenuItem('homeId')">Toggle menu entry 1</button>
        <button ng-click="toggleMenuItem('loginPageId')">Toggle menu entry 2</button>
        <button ng-click="toggleMenuItem('defineId')">Toggle menu entry 3</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS App / Controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('testController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.menuState = {
        homeId: false,
        loginPageId: false,
        defineId: false,
     };

    $scope.toggleMenuItem = function (menuId) {
      if (angular.isDefined($scope.menuState[menuId])) {
         $scope.menuState[menuId] = !$scope.menuState[menuId];
      }
    }
}]);
```