# Unknown ENV provider in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I writing one constant file with [Reff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42746036/how-to-load-js-file-which-contains-json-formate-in-angularjs/42746198?noredirect=1#comment72609976_42746198),
I getting the follwing Exception If I tried like that :

> ```
> angular.min.js:118 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=ENVProvider%20%3C-%20ENV%20%3C-%20viewRoleController
> ```

I get the error above in console:
My code as follows,

**jsp:-** included constant file location

**angularController**

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination','ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('viewRoleController', function($scope, $http, ENV, viewRoleService) {

    var dynamicData;

    $http.get('js/commons/AngularConstantFile.js').then(function (response) {
        dynamicData = response.data;
    });
});
```

**Constant file:-**

```
var app = angular.module('App');

app.constant("ENV", {
  "status412": "412",
  "Success": "Success",
});
```

Comment: You are the non accept answer boy. IMO, you should get no help. Still waiting for feedback here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978567/how-to-hide-a-link-by-using-ids also all other users on your questions still waiting for your feedback.

Comment: @lin thanks for your help, If my problem got solved then I will sure accept answer otherwise How Can I.

Comment: This is a poor lie m8. The most of your questions solved by good answer but you did not even give a feedback on it. Also my answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978567/how-to-hide-a-link-by-using-ids does solve your problem (where I spend a lot of time to give you a full qualified answer). You never called back, even if I asked you for. Sorry, but this is not how stackoverflow works.

Comment: @lin I will respect your sincerity on your kind helping nature. But really those answers are not satisfied my requirement. I dont thinks so It is your's problem. I think It is my understand problem. my apologies for that.I learnt new lession from here.

Comment: Give feedback on your other questions and mark right answers. You recived a lot of good answers on your questions. If a user writes a comment like `Are you using angularjs ? if so provide the code of your controller` - you should may going to answer this question, else how should the user be able to give you a right answer. If an other user ask you for feedback on his answer, you should give it to give the user a possibility to solve your problem. But the worst you can do is "nothing", like you did it on all your questions right now.

Comment: Take care of your other questions, bring some feedback and I will help you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like in this simple [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgquj3qy/1/). Ensure your config is loaded after your main application into DOM and you will be fine.

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, ENV) {
    $scope.ENV = ENV;
})

myApp.constant("ENV", {
  "status412": "412",
  "Success": "Success",
});
```

---

An other approach is do create your config in an own module and parse it into your main application like in this [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqxm08cg/). This will also work if your config is outsourced into an own file.

#### AnuglarJS application

```
var config = angular.module('config',[]).constant("ENV", {
  "status412": "412",
  "Success": "Success",
});

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['config']);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, ENV) {
    $scope.ENV = ENV;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your constant js file as follows, which will make sure to use the global instance of the module

```
angular.module('App').constant("ENV", {
  "status412": "412",
  "Success": "Success",
});
```

Comment: Hey Sajee, isnt it the same like getting the global module like `var app = angular.module('App');` and than procced with `app.constant...`?

Comment: Yep its the same, this doesnt solve the problem: https://plnkr.co/edit/7lGKHPMlUkL72RucWzlo?p=preview